# Column "ColumnName" does not belong to the table, dealing with datatable

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I am using vb.net and MS Access in the background as database. I am getting "Column "ColumnName" does not belong to the table" Below is my code:

```
      Dim comp As String
            Dim i As Integer = 1
            For Each row As DataRow In crossTable.Rows
                For Each r As DataRow In pptTable.Rows
                    Dim l As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lbl" & i), Label)
                    Dim c As ComboBox = CType(Me.Controls("cbo" & i), ComboBox)
                    If c.Text <> "" Then
                        'Get the cell value at this row for the l.text columnname
                        comp = row("'" & l.Text & "'")
                        If c.Text <> comp Then
                            row.Delete()
                        End If
                    End If
                    i += 1
                Next
            Next
```

I have two data tables I am looping through, when I reach to   comp = row("'" & l.Text & "'") it gives me this error. I have debug through several times, and my crosstable have all the correct column names and values then why does at that row it doesn't recognize that column name? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `l.Text` is "ColumnName" at some point. I would stick a break point in there and try to figure out when and why that happens.

Comment: which I did and it even shows the correct columnname but still, I have no idea why it would not work. Any way I did some work around it and got it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it possible the labels start at 0, not 1? Test by adding a console write or msgBox(comp) to see what the column name is passing as.

Comment: Try `Row.Item(...)` rather than just `Row(...)` and right now, from what I see, `"'" & l.Text & "'"` would return something that looks like `'MyCol'`... Do you want the `'` character for sure??

Comment: lbl started at 1, also row.Item(..) didn't work, I had already tried before posting question, I ended up getting the index of the columnname somehow and did row.Item(index). But how could I write "'" & l.Text & "'" in the way that it would return "Columnname" like it suppose to be.

Comment: Have you tried this (it would seem to be the correct way to do it)? `comp = row(l.Text)`.